# Magento 2 : Layered Navigation Filters, tag <a> and SEO link juice

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, seo

we're using Magento 2.2.1 with custom theme, which inherits Magento's default Layered navigation filters, which contains tag  with filtering attributes, what is not SEO friendly:

[image]

is there any solution (module, extension) which can help to solve this problem? or maybe some workaround?

Comment: There are many module/extensions that ajaxify the LayeredNavigation, which in turn removes the hard anchor-link. Although this isn't easy to do out-of-the-box, as the Category page is listening for the attributes passed through the Query string.

Comment: thanks, could you please recommend some?

Comment: or give me some keywords to find these modules?

Comment: Would be the same terminology, "Magento 2 layered navigation extensions". Arguably the most popular is [MagePlaza's  LayeredNavigation](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-layered-navigation-extension/)

Comment: Additionally, Magento have an [Magento's Partner program page](https://marketplace.magento.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=Layered%20Navigation#q=Layered%20Navigation&idx=m2_cloud_prod_default_products&p=0&fR%5Bext_platform%5D%5B0%5D=Magento%202&nR%5Bvisibility_search%5D%5B%3D%5D%5B0%5D=1&is_v=1) that show a version demos/versions.

Comment: ya, thanks, already found that one from mageplaza.

Answer (score 2):

You may check about using the [PRG Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to fix link juice and SEO issues caused by the endless number of unique URLs created by Layered Navigation.

Simply said, it's about replacing the GET request to a layered navigation/filter URL with a POST request (which search engine crawlers do not follow) before redirecting the user to the original layered navigation/filter URL.

This works like a charm, i. e. not changing the UX regarding Layered Navigation and 100% reliable in terms of preventing crawlers from wasting crawl budget on useless duplicate content URLs.

For further details and reading, please see

1. [Detailed explanation incl. sample request flow](https://medium.com/@jajuma/the-surprisingly-secret-seo-recipe-prg-pattern-for-advanced-layered-navigation-seo-b32c7cd441fc)
2. [Why robots.txt, rel=nofollow etc. are no satisfying solutions here](https://www.jajuma.de/en/blog/seo-optimization-for-layered-navigation-with-prg-pattern)
3. [PRG Pattern Magento 2 Extension](https://www.jajuma.de/en/jajuma-develop/extensions/prg-pattern-link-masking-for-magento-2)
4. [PRG Pattern Demo](https://demo.extension.jajuma.de/)